# Keep Getting The Same VirtualBox NTCreateFile Error

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

This (https://i.stack.imgur.com/mz4gP.png) is the error I always get when I try to open my VM in VirtualBox, and I have no idea what to do. Can anyone help?